# Vim start with cursor where last went off

Tags: vim, position, text-cursor

How do i make Vim always start at the line I was at when i exited that given file last time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put this in your .vimrc:

```
" When editing a file, always jump to the last cursor position
 au BufReadPost *
       \ if ! exists("g:leave_my_cursor_position_alone") |
       \     if line("'\"") > 0 && line ("'\"") <= line("$") |
       \         exe "normal g'\"" |
       \     endif |
       \ endif
```

then you can use `:let g:leave_my_cursor_position_alone=1` at runtime to deactivate the feature.

Answer (score 4):

put this into your .vimrc

```
set viewoptions=cursor,folds

au BufWinLeave * mkview

au BufWinEnter * silent loadview
```